# Python: Avoid repetition with .get('')

Tags: python

I currently have the following lines of code where I write `sentiment_score.get(` over and over. Is there a better / smarter way to write that?

```
sentiment = detect_sentiment.get('Sentiment')
sentiment_score = detect_sentiment['SentimentScore']
mixed = sentiment_score.get('Mixed')
negative = sentiment_score.get('Negative')
neutral = sentiment_score.get('Neutral')
positive = sentiment_score.get('Positive')
```

Comment: it's difficult to say without seeing how these variables are being used

Comment: @asongtoruin  Absolutely without the code snippet we can't say anything

Comment: Can you use the `dict[key]` variable further in your code without assigning it to an extra variable?

Comment: I use these variables to save them in the database with Django: 
`NLP.objects.create(
                answer=answer_obj,
                language=language,
                sentiment=sentiment,
                mixed=mixed,
                negative=negative,
                neutral=neutral,
                positive=positive,
            )`

Comment: Is that the only place you're using them? If so, there's no real point in assigning them to variables, you could just pass them directly to the function.

Comment: Yes, that's the only time. You have a good point there. I will just use them directly and save the extra lines.

Answer (score 4):

Not as compact as @mohit-solanki 's solution, but more linter friendly:

```
mixed, negative, neutral, positive = [
    sentiment_score.get(i) for i in [
      'Mixed', 'Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive',
]]
```

...and more coder-friendly as well, IMHO ;-)

Comment: I like this one more :)

Answer (score 1):

```
mixed, negative, neutral, positive = [detect_sentiment['SentimentScore'][key] for key in ['Mixed', 'Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably ugly but you can do this

```py
for name in ['Mixed', 'Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive']:
    locals()[name.lower()] = sentiment_score.get(name)
```

`locals()` returns a dictionary containing the local scope [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that linters and IDE will probably not be smart enough to notice the existence of variables`mixed`, `negative` etc... and hence will bother you with spurious warning when you will further use them. At least, pylint 2.3.1 is not.

Comment: better to create a new dictionary that you populate rather than add too `locals()`

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine I agree that will probably confuse all the linters and that's why I said it's a ugly hack